# the facts of providing a home with another family

Tags: parsing

> the fact of providing a home in an institution run by the local authority for children who cannot live with their parents or the fact of providing **a home with another family** for children who cannot live with their parents.

Source: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/care_1?q=Care

---

1. Is "**a home with another family**" a noun phrase?
2. Is "**a home**" modified adjectivally by "**with another family**"?
3. Would you give me some examples of "**with**"?

Answer (score 1):

- a boy with another hat
- a lady with another car
- a person with another name

*with* is a preposition and with [determiner] [noun] is a *prepositional phrase*. In the examples above the prepositional phrase modifies the first noun.

With meaning ‘having’
We use with to mean ‘having’ or ‘possessing’:
[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/with#google_vignette)

Comment: Could "which is used by" be substituted for "**with**" in that context?

Comment: @Aaaaaaassssss That does not sound like a serious question. Why don't *you* write out an example with that phrase and see?

Answer (score 0):

2 is correct. You'll see that if you remove "with another family" the meaning doesn't change as such, there is just less information. "Home" here means somewhere to live.